# EmguCV : How to Detect whether the file has reached end of file using QueryFrame()

Tags: ocr, video-processing, emgucv

I am using Emgucv to capture frames from a video file Here is my Code

```
private void Frame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        try
        {
            timesbetweenframes++;
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = FrameExtractor.QueryFrame();
            if (timesbetweenframes == 10 || timesbetweenframes == 0)
            {

                if (frame != null)
                {
                    Bgr min = new Bgr(65, 65, 65);
                    Bgr threshold = new Bgr(128, 128, 128);
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame2 = frame;
                    //Noise Removal 
                    frame._SmoothGaussian(5);

                    VideoBox.Image = Frame2;
                    Bgr drawColor = new Bgr(Color.Blue);
                    using (Image<Gray, byte> gray = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
                    {
                        TextExtract.Recognize(gray);
                        Tesseract.Charactor[] charactors = TextExtract.GetCharactors();
                        foreach (Tesseract.Charactor c in charactors)
                        {
                            Frame2.Draw(c.Region, drawColor, 1);
                        }

                    }
                    cptrdImage.Image = frame;
                    String text = TextExtract.GetText();
                    //removal of noise in this section 
                    Tags.Items.Add(text);
                    WriteData(text, fileName,frame);
                    fileName++;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
                    FrameExtractor = null;
                    InProgress = false;
                    timer1.Elapsed -= Frame;
                }
                timesbetweenframes = 0;
            }

        }
```

The frame function is being added to the timer event , this automatically fires the frame function after every 500 ms and extracting every 10th frame .Now the problem is that after calling queryframe() function , the program crashes with an error: 
"The instriction at 0x7777f7a99 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory coudl not be read" after sometime.

Am i using it the wrong way , or is there any other way of doing this without getting this error .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the time (500 ms) is too short ??

I would attach this function to a Application.Idle event and if need more delay then Thread.Sleep(neededTime - consumedTimeByFrameFunction)
That's way that you will eliminate possible timing issue.